# Connecting to an Oozie Server

Tags: oozie

I'm trying to connect to Oozie on localhost and the standard command shows connection timeout. The server says it's running when I write

```
oozied.sh run
```

When I try accessing http://localhost:11000 it says connection refused. How can I connect to the localhost server?

```
Validate DB Connection
[org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
1079  oozie-derby  INFO   [main] openjpa.Runtime - OpenJPA dynamically loaded the class enhancer. Any classes that were not enhanced at build time will be "org.apache.oozie.client.rest.JsonCoordinatorJob" listed in the openjpa.MetaDataFactory configuration property could not be loaded by sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1b6d3586; ignoring.
5620  oozie-derby  WARN   [main] openjpa.MetaData - The class "org.apache.oozie.client.rest.JsonWorkflowJob" listed in the openjpa.MetaDataFactory configuration property could not be loaded by sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1b6d3586; ignoring.
5622  oozie-derby  WARN   [main] openjpa.MetaData - ient.rest.JsonWorkflowAction" listed in the openjpa.MetaDataFactory configuration property could not be loaded by sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1b6d3586; ignoring.
5741  oozie-derby  WARN   [main] openjpa.MetaData - The class "org.apache.oozie.client.rest.JsonCoordinatorAction" listed in the openjpa.MetaDataFactory configuration property could not be loaded by sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1b6d3586; ignoring.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2573)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2538)
    at org.apache.oozie.util.XConfiguration.getClassByName(XConfiguration.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClasses(Configuration.java:2611)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.ConfigurationService$LogChangesConfiguration.getClasses(ConfigurationService.java:413)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.ConfigurationService.getClasses(ConfigurationService.java:609)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.ActionService.init(ActionService.java:61)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.setServiceInternal(Services.java:387)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.setService(Services.java:373)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.loadServices(Services.java:304)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.init(Services.java:212)
    at org.apache.oozie.server.guice.ServicesProvider.get(ServicesProvider.java:31)
    at org.apache.oozie.server.guice.ServicesProvider.get(ServicesProvider.java:25)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)

This is most of my output from oozied.run
```

Comment: Well, is the Oozie server actually running?

Comment: It says running when I use oozied.sh start, but it refuses to connect. @OneCricketeer

Comment: Try `oozied.sh run` instead and edit your question with the output from that